# Delete number of string characters from left in Column B depending on length of string in column A of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

As described in the title, I have the following problem:

Data is prepared as a pandas dataframe incoming as follows:

| Article | Title |
| --- | --- |
| A0 | A00183 |
| BB2 | BB2725 |
| C2C3 | C2C3945 |

As you can see, the "Title" column is repeating the string value of the `Article` column.

I want this to be deleted, so that the table looks as follows:

| Article | Title |
| --- | --- |
| A0 | 0183 |
| BB2 | 725 |
| C2C3 | 945 |

I want to do this with Pandas.

I already found out how to read the length of the string row in column `Article`, so that I already know the amount of characters to be deducted with this:

```
df1['Length of Article string:'] = df1['Article:'].apply(len)
```

But now I am to stupid to figure out how to delete the strings, that can change in amount for every row, in the `Title` column.

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards

Tried Pandas Documentation, found some hints regarding split and strip, but I do not have enough know-how to implement...

Comment: What would happen with AB and AA0123, AAA and AA0123 and, A and AA0123?

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `df['Article'].str.len().value_counts()`?

Comment: Too bad you didn't answer the question, you could have had a more efficient solution than `replace` with a list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace from list derived from Article column.

```
df["Title"] = df["Title"].replace(df["Article"].tolist(), "", regex=True)
print(df)

  Article Title
0      AA  0123
1     BBB   234
2    CCCC   345
```

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks for this! Works perfectly well - but is also very slow in performance. It took more than 2 minutes to run (the input is around 40k rows. Any other more performant ideas?

Comment: Hey Jason, today I ran into the first error:
"/sre_parse.py:668 in _parseraise source.error("nothing to repeat", error: nothing to repeat"
Do you have any idea want went wront? The code ran through perfectly well over 80% of my data but it keeps crashing at the same spot. Could it be some incompatible letter/sign?

Comment: IDK it works with NaN and blanks,  and an iterable value would raise a different error. Would have to know what the value was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **replace()** with a lambda function.

```
dfx = df[['Article','Title']].apply(lambda x : x['Title'].replace((x['Article']), ''), axis=1)
```

Comment: Don't think the OP wants the int conversion as their example output for the first row remains `0123`

Comment: yes, I shouldn't have added that. I edited my answer.

Comment: Good idea, but in fact the Article as well as Title strings are mixed, I have updated to example to be more specific. Thanks anyway!

Comment: okey, i updated my answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: Hi,
this is not working, get an error:
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3775 in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
Seems like there is a case in the dataset, where your solution has issues

Comment: okey, i edited answer. Can you run it again and see how many rows the dfx has? and can you check that it is equal to df's row count ?